# Auto redirect to external authority when user is not authorized using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and OIDC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm trying to secure my ASP.NET MVC web application using an external authorization server over OpenID Connect Protocol (specifically - KeyCloak, but I think it's not so important).
All the examples I have to find are basically to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` nuget package and add some configuration code to Startup class:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = authUrl;
        options.ClientId = clientId;
        options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    });
```

Then if I add `[Authorized]` attribute to the controller action, when I try to open the page, I'll be redirected to the `/Identity/Account/Login` system page, where in the section `Use another service to log in.` appears the button `OpenIdConnect` to login through a remote authentication server.

This button works - it redirects to the authorization server, and after a successful login opens `/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin` with a proposal to fill in the missing user claims for local registration (in particular - email).
In fact, of course, the address `/signin-oidc` is opening first, which handler, I believe, completes the authentication procedure based on the received authorization code.

However, I don't need any other authorization methods except OpenIDConnect. I need an unauthorized user to be immediately redirected to a remote authorization server.

How can I prevent other login methods and redirect directly to the authorization server, but not to the ASP.NET login page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I don't need any other authorization methods except OpenIDConnect. I need an unauthorized user to be immediately redirected to a remote authorization server.
>
> How can I prevent other login methods and redirect directly to the authorization server, but not to the ASP.NET login page?

Indeed, there's a way to redirect to authorization server directly without accessing any local login page.

But typically we still need another `SignInScheme`.If you look into the source code, you will find out that when the remote authentication handler succeeds to authenticate some user, it will then [sign the user in](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L140):

> ```
>    // ...
>    await Context.SignInAsync(SignInScheme, ticketContext.Principal, ticketContext.Properties);
>    // ...
> ```

For example, if the `OAuth2.0` authentication succeeds, we should **set a cookie or issue a JWT token** for current user.

---

As for your question, the easiest way is to register a cookie scheme to Challenge / Signin :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("MyOIDC", options =>
    {
        // ...
    }
```

And now you could use `[Authorize]` as you like. The above code works flawlessly for me without the [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Identity)

**[Update]**: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we must custom the challenge process:

1. Approach 1 : configure a forward challenge scheme for Cookie:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>{
        options.ForwardChallenge ="MyOIDC";

    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("MyOIDC", options =>
    {
         // ....
    }
```

2. Approach 2 : invoke challenge scheme manually :

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("MyOIDC", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
        }
        
        // if you need sign out the MyOIDC service, you could sign out the user for two schemes as below :
        [Authorize]
        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("MyOIDC", new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
            });
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

Comment: After this I've got redirect to `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F`, but not to the authority service. How can I change that behaviour?

Comment: @Emanuel Sorry, I forgot to mention that we must custom the challenge process.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Maybe you can also explain, why `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` into `_LoginPartial.cshtml` now returns false, no matter that user is actually authorized and I can read his claims?

Comment: @Emanuel  [`SignInManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is defined in **ASP.NET Core Identity**. As we have never used ASP.NET Core Identity here, it surely won't work.